# Click on a Button with python

Tags: python, selenium, button

I am a learning python right now and try to finalize my second script.

I know how to click on an element by Id, text and ngclick from selenium - but none of these worked for my current one so far :/

This element is completely new to me - I am trying to click on this button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Found something in the previous questions which is

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("btn").click()
```

but have no idea what driver is referring to :-)

Can somebody help a drowning beginner?^^

Best
Vanassins

Comment: looks like they're using selenium. Take a look at the docs, it's pretty cool

Comment: Selenium has documentation to show you how to get started with it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: SO is not intended as a tutorial site but instead for answering specific questions on programming. It sounds like you are looking for some tutorials. If you do some googling, you will find a LOT of tutorials that will teach you the basics of python and/or Selenium.

Comment: Big thanks for all your answers and advices! It's indeed selenium I am using. Will look for some more documents on it, so far I have looked up a lot examples and YT videos, but looks like there's indeed much more I have to learn.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

- Create a WebDriver instance.
- Navigate to a Web page.
- Locate an HTML element from UI.
- Perform an action on an HTML element.
- Run tests and record test results using a test framework.

Sample Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
input_element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
input_element.send_keys("Test Selenium")
input_element.submit()
```

Comment: OP's basic question was _...no idea what driver is referring to..._, can you shed some light in your answer please.

Comment: WebDriver is not a web automation framework and it doesn't use a programming language to create test scripts. It's an API to drive the browser. You should perhaps understand the topic before attempting to answer questions. See [the docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

Comment: Thank you very much, the sample example helped me a lot to understand what driver means! Will test around with these piece of code! :-)

Comment: @Vanassins: Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.